# Cost of putting CSS Transitions on all elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

I often find myself adding transitions to a lot of things, and often they are the same transition. What would be the performance cost of just doing something like

```
* { 
   transition: all 200ms ease; //with prefixes, of course
}
```

and just setting a `transition-property: none;` to elements you specifically didn't want transitioning? Would it be less than the amount of code required to add multiple transition statements throughout your code?

EDIT: For those wondering about the complexity of the DOM this applied to, assume it is a complex web-app-type DOM. The reason I ask is because many elements on the page don't move and thus don't require the transition. I am curious as to whether or not that is relevant and merely assigning transitions to all elements is detrimental to performance.

Comment: The answer to your second question depends exactly on how many elements you want to add transitions to

Comment: You may need a Cray to render a complex page ^^

Comment: @AndreaLigios what is a Cray?

Comment: lol... legacy supercomputers

Comment: The `*` selector alone is not costly. The property though, will depend on how each browser interprets it to define the cost of static elements that don't transition.

Comment: For someone who knows what I'm asking, an appropriate answer might be, "For each element that a transition is applied to, the browser must do X and that carries a performance penalty of Y. A modern computer can handle [n(Y) performance penalties] without skipping a beat, but if you go over that, you're looking to slow down the responsiveness of your page. [However, if the elements do not move, said penalty is not incurred/still occurs]"

Comment: A very good question, would love to know it myself, but don't have time to benchmark.

Comment: Some related reading: http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/ seems to suggest that this may be unnecessary micro optimizing...

Answer (score 2):

When they are not transitioning they are not consuming extra resources, so after rendering it's the same, assuming you have removed all the unnecessary transitions.